# How to set page number on each page in window.print() in Chrome by removing browser's default header and footer

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am using window.print() in html code.
i need to add my new footer with page number on each pages and i am using chrome. 
i removed the default header and footer by adding and to repeat new header and footer in every pages of print I used table style with thead and tfoot.

I am attaching my code below

```
   @page{
   margin: 0; // disabling browser's header and footer
   }
```

```
<table>
       <thead>
          header content
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td colspan="2">
                <!---- dynamic contents here -->
             </td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
          footer content
       </tfoot>
    </table>
```

i need to print page number on every pages and it could work on both chrome and mozila 
    Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe **window.print()** can be configured. According to its documentation it does not take in any arguments. It makes use of the browser's built in print function to directly print or save the page.

Although the browser GUI provides you with some options that is available on the screen during printing.